# How setState call build in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, statefulwidget

I know `build` will be called everytime `setState` called and I want to find the method chain in the flutter framework.

So I check the source code of flutter and find some steps of `setState`:

1. `_element!.markNeedsBuild()` mark state's element dirty. [image] [image]
2. `owner!.scheduleBuildFor(this)` call `BuildOwner`'s `onBuildScheduled` and add element to the dirty elements list. [image]
3. `BuildOwner`'s `onBuildScheduled` is assigned in `WidgetsBinding`'s `initInstances()`:[image]
   [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]
4. And `WidgetsBinding`'s `initInstances()` is called in `runApp()`. [image] [image]

I had check carefully but **didn't see any code call `state`'s `build` method**.

How `setState` call `build` in flutter internal？ Can we find any source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `handleDrawFrame()` you see this part:

```
try {
  // PERSISTENT FRAME CALLBACKS
  _schedulerPhase = SchedulerPhase.persistentCallbacks;
  for (final FrameCallback callback in _persistentCallbacks) {
    _invokeFrameCallback(callback, _currentFrameTimeStamp!);
  }
```

I don't know exactly where it's added to the `persistenCallbacks` but looking at that variable in the code shows you

```
  /// The persistent callbacks (scheduled by
  /// [SchedulerBinding.addPersistentFrameCallback]) are currently executing.
  ///
  /// Typically, this is the build/layout/paint pipeline. See
  /// [WidgetsBinding.drawFrame] and [SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame].
  persistentCallbacks,
```

Meaning it calls `drawFrame`

Inside `drawFrame` you'll find this line:

```
    buildOwner!.buildScope(rootElement!);
```

And inside this method it looks through all elements in `_dirtyElements`. Note that in `scheduleBuildFor` that you posted in this question it wass added to this. So in this `buildScope` it calls

```
element.rebuild();
```

This in turn calls

```
performRebuild():
```

which for `ComponentElements` says

```
  /// Calls the [StatelessWidget.build] method of the [StatelessWidget] object
  /// (for stateless widgets) or the [State.build] method of the [State] object
  /// (for stateful widgets) and then updates the widget tree.
  ///
  /// Called automatically during [mount] to generate the first build, and by
  /// [rebuild] when the element needs updating.
  @override
  @pragma('vm:notify-debugger-on-exception')
  void performRebuild() {
```